# JQuery do click events stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have the following code;

```
$("#myID").click(function () {
    //do something
})
```

At some point, a user action on another part of the webpage needs to change the action that occurs on the click e.g.

```
$("#myID").click(function () {
    //do something different
})
```

My question is, what's the correct/most efficient way of doing this? Currently I'm just implementing the second chunk of code above, but will this cause some odd behaviour? i.e. will there now be two different actions performed on click? Or does the second block of code override the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will both execute so no, the second call does not overwrite the first.

**[Basic jsFiddle example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/j08691/J8BQe/)**

And as pimvdb notes, they will be executed in the order they were bound.

Comment: More specifically, the handlers will be executed in the order they were bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can always unbind the click function first: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

Right, they "stack". I.e. $("#myID") will maintain a list of event handlers, and execute both on click.

If you no longer want the original handler, you need to unbind it, using `$("#myID").off('click')` or if you're using an old version of jquery, `$("#myID").unbind('click'`)`. http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

In your code, both clicks will be executed. 
Try to unbind click event before

```
$("#myID").unbind("click")
```

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global variable `isAnotherEvent = false` and then check on `click` event which part of code you need to execute, to execute another part simply make `isAnotherEvent = true`

```
var isAnotherEvent = false;
$("#myID").click(function () {
  if(!isAnotjerEvent){
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
})

$("#btnChangeEvent").click(function(){
  isAnotherEvent = true;
}
```